# Skip taskB taskC when task A is failed even though conditions of taskB & taskC are met

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-yaml

Q1: I have a single job in ADO YAML pipeline which have 4-5 tasks under steps. I want to trigger those tasks based on few conditions so I've used ADO Expressions. But now i want to skip the taskB when taskA fails. By default it should happen but seems like my task condition is overriding the continueonerror:false

Can you suggest how to do this ?
tried alternative workaround: Multi Job Pipeline setup with 1 task in 1 job & it works fine for us, but want to know how we can setup for multiple tasks in a single job ?

Q2 : Even if i can get taskA status as a variable using REST API & set variable concepts, how can i add multiple conditions in task.something like " variable1=succeeded & variable2 = p1 or variable3 = p2 "

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops

Sample yaml

```
parameters:

variables:

trigger:

steps:
  task: A
  continueonerror:false
condition: or(eq(v1, p3), eq(v2, 3), eq(v4, 5))

  task: B
  continueonerror:false
condition: or(eq(v1, p1), eq(v2, 6))

  task: C
  continueonerror:false
condition: or(eq(v1, p2), eq(v2, 8))
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you mention ADO. My assumption is that you mean AzDo (Azure DevOps) Right?

Comment: Hi, have you got a chance to check the suggestion below? If the answer works for you, you may consider [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to your expectation to skip `TaskB` if `TaskA` fails, you may consider adding `succeeded()` as part of the condition in `TaskB` together with your other evaluations. Kindly take the following sample YAML for a reference.

```
trigger: none
parameters:
- name: p1
  default: 1
- name: p2
  default: 2
- name: p3
  default: 3
variables:
  v1: 2
  v2: 6
  v3: 2
  v4: 5

steps:
- script: |
    echo A
    echo "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Simulate task failure."
    exit 1
  name: TaskA
# continueOnError: true
  condition: or(eq(variables['v1'], ${{ parameters.p3 }}), eq(variables['v2'], 3), eq(variables['v4'], 5))
- script: echo B
  name: TaskB
  condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables['v1'], ${{ parameters.p1 }}), eq(variables['v2'], 6)))
- script: echo C
  name: TaskC
  condition: and(succeededOrFailed(), or(eq(variables['v1'], ${{ parameters.p2 }}), eq(${{ parameters.p2 }}, 8)))
```

When `TaskA` failed the condition evaluation of `succeeded()` for `TaskB` would be `False`; hence `TaskB` was skipped.

`TaskC` uses `succeededOrFailed()` in its condition and will continue to run, even if a previous dependency has failed, unless the run was canceled.

See more information on [Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages).

[image: Skipped TaskB]